# $_POST is empty after requesting by POST lwp-request

Tags: php, post, lwp

I'm sending POST request from command line (Ubuntu):

```
echo -n '{"prop":"value"}' | POST -c -U "application/json" http://site.com/test
```

Server script outputs its $_POST:

```
<?php 
  var_dump ($_POST);
?>
```

I see in output: `Content-Length: 16`, but in response of server I get

```
array(0){
}
```

Where have I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` contains the key-value pairs of the data submitted as normal form data.  Because you sent JSON data, it doesn't get parsed the same.

You need to retrieve the request body.  You can either use `http_get_request_body()` or treat the body as a file using `fopen('php://input')`.  Once you have read the request body, you can use `json_decode()` to parse it.

```
$x = json_decode(http_get_request_body());
```

See:

- **[http_get_request_body](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php)**
- **[I/O stream wrappers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)**

Comment: Thank you. I understood. In my case I can send key:value pairs, I don't need exact json. So `echo -n 'prop=value' | POST http://site.com/test` worked in my case